# How to validate an numeric input in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying a build a simple calculator in node.js which also should validate the inputs. Below is the following code

```js
process.stdout.write('A simple calculator created using node.js \n');

var inputs = ['Please enter your first number','Please enter the second number','Please enter the operator'];
var output1 = [];

function ask(i) {
 process.stdout.write(`${inputs[i]}`);
 process.stdout.write(" : ");
}
ask(0);
process.stdin.on('data',(data)=> {
 if(typeof data != "number"){
  console.log(ask(0));
 } else {
 output1.push(data); 
 console.log('The given input is ' + output1);
}
}
);
```

I would want the console to loop back to the function ask() if my input is not a number. Below should be the ideal output

Output :
Please enter your first number : p
Please enter your first number : 1
The given input is 1

I know there are some flaws in my code, but not sure how to correct it. Pls help.

Comment: Searching for the isNaN() method on Google might help. The parseFloat() method could also be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback to `process.stdin.on` will receive the `Buffer` object as the argument.

```
process.stdin.on('data', data => {
    /** data will be buffer. */
});
```

You will need to convert the `Buffer` to `String` using `toString()` method. Once you have the `String`, you can try to parse the string to a number (Int or Float) using methods of `Number` class ( `Number.parseInt` or `Number.parseFloat` ). You can then check if the number you parsed was a valid number or not using `Number.isNaN` method.

Here is how the code would look like:

```
process.stdin.on('data', data => {
    var string = data.toString();
    var number = Number.parseFloat(string);
    if (Number.isNaN(number)) {
        ask(0);
    } else {
        output1.push(number);
        console.log('The given input is ' + output1);
    }
});
```

To give you a hint on how to finish the whole calculator, I would create a `indexOfInput` and maintain it on the inputs:

```
var indexOfInput = 0;
ask(indexOfInput);
process.stdin.on('data', data => {
    var string = data.toString();
    var number = Number.parseFloat(string);
    if (Number.isNaN(number)) {
        ask(indexOfInput);
    } else {
        output1.push(number);
        console.log('The given input is ' + output1);
        // Current input taken successfully. Let's take the next input
        indexOfInput++;
        ask(indexOfInput);
    }
});
```

You will need to further add make tweaks to make it work completely. You will need something like this somewhere in your code.

```
if (indexOfInput <= 1) {
    /** expecting number */
} else if (indexOfInput === 2) {
    /** expecting an operator */
} else {
    /** all the inputs taken. process the inputs array */
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It works fine. Thanks. But, can you explain why do we need to convert the buffer to string and then to a float? I'm new to node.js and it would be of great help if you can help me briefing on this. Thanks